# Python: Return top n lists from sublist having maximum length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists, where each sublist is a list of objects.
The task is to return a list of top n sublists in the descending order of their length.

Illustration:

`[[{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{}],[{},{}],[{}],[]]`

For above, I want to return a list of top 3 sublists as per length, which is

`[[{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{}],[{},{}]]`

as the sublists have largest length 3,2,1 respectively from the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible options, let's say:

```
l = [[{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{}],[{},{}],[{}],[]]
```

You can produce a completely new list and take the desired 3 elements:

```
sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Or, you can sort your original list and them take the first 3 elements:

```
l.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
l[:3]
```

In terms of performance, the second option seems faster:

```
In [1]: %timeit sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)[:3]
1.9 µs ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [2]: %%timeit
    ...: l.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    ...: l[:3]
    ...: 
1.22 µs ± 33.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: here the task is to return a list (not modify from question). So ```sorted``` would suite more.

Comment: @Siddharth, I agree, but it seems that in terms of performance modifying the list seems is faster than making a copy of the new list.

Comment: @ lmiguelvargasf just upvoted your answer for the same

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [[{},{},{},{}],[{},{},{}],[{},{}],[{}],[]]
>>> sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True)
[[{}, {}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}], [{}], []]
```

You can always choose select top `k` after splicing the result of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) by `sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True)[0:k]`.

Main observation to note is argument `key`, which can also accept any crazy [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function too.